# Web service with no input params

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I need to create a web service method which is not supposed to take any params. I'm using jax-ws and apache xref for generation Java sources from wsdl. I cannot omit input message (an error occurs). What is the best way for doing this? So far I have found the following solution

```
<message name="getTermRequest" />

<message name="getTermResponse">
  <part name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</message>

<portType name="glossaryTerms">
  <operation name="getTerm">
    <input message="getTermRequest"/>
    <output message="getTermResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
```

but may be you can suggest something better?

Comment: You are creating one wsdl from scratch and then generating the java classes?

Comment: @Sérgio Yep, Let's say I'm creating one wsdl from scratch and then generating the java classes. (Actually, I'm adding another web method to an existing wsdl, but that doesn't make any difference I guess)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify an existing wsdl file (this seems to be a rpc/lit wsdl) then the method you have done is fine. You can not delete the input message since that make the web service operation out only one.

But if you can start with the POJO code (i.e code first) then you can write a service method parameter less way and let framework to generate the wsdl.